# Put all the files starting with same prefix in a folder in linux

Tags: linux, file, grouping

I have different files in some old data.

They are in the same folder.

They are grouped by the prefix.

I want to move all the files starting with the same prefix in a folder named with the same prefix.

Looking for a script which does it automatically.

**EDIT 1**
The script has to look by itself that how many prefixes are there and then group

Thanks

Comment: A script? Why not `mkdir prefix && mv prefix* prefix`?

Comment: well I dont know all the prefixes in advance, the script will find all the prefixes as well

Comment: And how is a script supposed to determine what is a prefix and what isn't? You might need to show some representative data, in addition to what you have tried that isn't working... Technically speaking, every single file name is a (unique) prefix, but I suspect what you're thinking of is limited to some (possibly non-uniform) subset of the file names, but how is a script to know where the prefix ends and the suffix begins? Is it just 4 characters, or 17, or delimited by `_` or something else entirely?...

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, how about an `ls -1` listing of all the files, piping to an `awk` command to get all the unique prefixes:

```
xxx
yyy
zzz
www
...
```

Then, use the output of the `awk` commmand and loop through to create the prefix directory and move all files into it as @Noufal Ibrahim suggested:

```
mkdir ${prefix} && mv ${prefix}* prefix
```

I'm no awk expert, but off the top of my head, I'm thinking the awk script would be something along the lines of:

```
BEGIN {
    // initialize associative array $x
}

{ $x[prefix($0)] = 1; }

END {
   // foreach key in $x:
       print $key
}
```